# Failed: Template parse errors: 'mat-card' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular6

When I'm running Karma "ng test" for my project, I'm getting below error,

Failed: Template parse errors: 'mat-card' is not a known element

But the application is working fine with mat-card tag when we run "ng serve". We are using angular 6. requesting guidance on this.

Comment: Please, if possible, post the test code and the relevant part of the component being tested (ts + html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a component which contains a custom form control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821486/how-to-test-a-component-which-contains-a-custom-form-control)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add all the necessary modules in your test spec which are utilized by your component file. In your case you are missing `MdCardModule`.

```
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [ 
        MdCardModule, 
],
```

Else if you don't care those elements, you may simply add

```
schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]  // not recommended, because it will hide all the errors
```